# Execution issues with Python "concurrent.futures" threads

Tags: python, multithreading, ssh, concurrent.futures

In a nutshell, I have written a Python Script that attempts to establish SSH connections (using the Paramiko module) to some 600 network devices and then issues a simple command, parsing and returning the output.

I have ran my script without threading, and it works as expected so I know my issue is with the threading aspect(or my understanding of it). My only prior experience with Threading is in C...

Here is my use of futures:

```
with futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
    for x in nodeList:
        futureSSH = {executor.submit(connectHost,node): node for node in x.nodes}
        for future in futures.as_completed(futureSSH):
            print future.running()
            successes.append(futureSSH[future])
            counter +=1
            print counter
```

and here is the function that attemps SSH connection:

```
def connectHost(node):

    myList = [],USERNAME = '#######',   MY_PASSWORD = '########' ,nodeNeighbors = nodeHierarchy(),counter = 0

    for i in range(10):
        try:
            print ("success")
            ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
            ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
            print ("Attempting connection")
            ssh.connect(node,username = USERNAME,password = MY_PASSWORD, timeout = 10)
            print ("Connection established")
            stdin,stdout,stderr = ssh.exec_command('show cdp ne')

            ###Pattern match output here###
            break

        except Exception as error:
            continue
    else:
        return None
```

Now everything with this works PERFECTLY. Other than the fact that on the 153rd iteration my scripts seems to freeze, only to resume after about 10 minutes. This repeats off and on for the rest of the execution.

What puzzles me, is that I have a maximum number of 10 active threads attempting SSH connections a maximum of 10 times, with a timeout of 10 seconds on each attempt. So my understanding is that at the very WORST case, a single thread would sit idle for 100 seconds until exiting... Since this isn't the case, does it having something to do with threads hanging around or locking?

Comment: I'd guess this was more likely to be to do with the ssh/networking than the threads.  Do you need to disconnect from your ssh clients?  (e.g. with .close()).   Can I suggest you run it through a profiler?  Might be a quick way of working out where the problem lies.

Comment: Haha, I totally forgot about .close(). Go figure 150 unclosed connections could lead to some weird behavior...It's not running perfectly now, but it's in a much more debugable state. I'll give the profiler a shot, thanks for the suggestions!